# How do I get my Windows Server 2012 Hyper-V VM hosted on Win 8 to use Integration Services?

Tags: windows-8, hyper-v, windows-server-2012

I'm unable to get my Server 2012 Hyper-V VM to work seamlessly in Win 8.

I have a Windows 7 VM that integrates nicely with the host OS. The mouse works as I would expect and I'm able to connect to the net via the virtual external network switch I configured.

For my Server 2012 VM, I've set it to use the same external switch but am unable to get a network connection. I installed the Integration Services on my Windows 7 (Action->Insert Integration Services Setup Disk) and have tried the same with Server 2012. My understanding is that this step isn't necessary because Integration Services are built into Server 2012.

I've searched for info about necessary services or Windows components that need to be installed but have come up empty so far.  Does anyone know what step(s) I missed for my Server VM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the specific flavour of Windows Server that I'm trying to virtualize is the issue (Windows Server 2012 Foundation). I guess this was a significant detail.

In one of Paul Thurrott's posts I found this tidbit: "(You can virtualize Essentials on Windows Server 2012 Standard or Datacenter, but not Foundation: Remember, it comes with new server hardware only.)" Here's the link to the original article - http://windowsitpro.com/windows-server-2012/windows-server-2012-foundation-vs-essentials